# Golang build executable for IBM I

Tags: go, mainframe

My IBM I is running on OS400, kernal-release 4, version 7, processor powerpc.

I made a 'hello world' go project, below are build examples I've tried, but I haven't built a compatible executable for the IBM I.

```
GOARCH=ppc64 GOOS=aix go build
GOARCH=ppc64 GOOS=linux go build
CC=powerpc-ibm-aix-gccgo GOOS=aix GOARCH=ppc64 go build
```

I am looking into building with gcc-go, but I'm still unsure what settings I need in order to run on the IBM I.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You wrote "below is one example" without actually showing us the Go program source, the command you used to compile it, or the result of running the resulting program. Having said that it looks like you might be trying to cross-compile a Go program so the binary runs on the OS400 platform. But your question is so incoherent I can't conclude what problem you need help with.

Comment: @KurtisRader Yes, I am trying to `build` a Go 'hello world' program where the binary runs on the OS400.

Comment: this link was posted by @sumitgoyal, and his answer was deleted because the moderation doesn't allow links to active and open discussions posted as answers.
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45017 . It is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

On IBMi there is multiple File system : Native IBMi Objects (/QSYS) or Linux/Unix like filesystem (/qopensys), etc.
there is then multiple Compiler corresponding  to those file system gcc is available into the / ou /qopensys, but not accurate into /QSYS one. for so called Native IBMi object *PGM (a program) the compiler is on native command lien CRTCMOD (Create C module) or CRTCPPMOD (Create C++ module. it will create a *MODULE Object you need to "bind" to a *PGM with the CRTPGM command for example

for gcc, you have to be into the Linux/unix file system (STRQSH from native OS command line) and then use it as any gcc on linux to make it.

in both case they will work only on their respective environment

hope this help.